# Ruby Converting dollar integer into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, formatting

I have this `integer` `float` dollar `1,712.00`. In ruby how can I change this dollar into `String`?

example:
`1,712.00` => `ONE THOUSAND SEVEN HUNDRED AND TWELVE ONLY`

Is there an easy way to do this in ruby on rails? Or does someone have code that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "integer float dollar"?

Comment: I mean this dollar `1,712.00`. Sorry if my explanation is not clear. point is I want this number `1,712.00` convert to this `String` `ONE THOUSAND SEVEN HUNDRED AND TWELVE ONLY`

Comment: Whatever it is, it looks like it's already a string. Isn't it?

Comment: No, I want that number convert to `alphabet`

Comment: @MarsAtomic  Sorry. I'm really new in `Ruby on Rails`. I know what is `gem` but I'm not really sure I can understand your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [number_and_words](https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words) gem that you can use.

Put `gem 'numbers_and_words'` in your `Gemfile` and use it like:

```
I18n.with_locale(:en) { 1712.to_words }
```

Another option is to use the [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize) gem.